# How to fix react-native-gesture-handler error not working

Tags: react-native

I create a new project in react-native ,then install (`npm install --save react-navigation` `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`),
the latest version (react-native: 0.60.0) auto linking so,I not link ,but still is showing error,
!https://prnt.sc/oaxxuc

`Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac **FAILED**`

After I uninstall gesture-handler this kind of error showing
!https://prnt.sc/oaxx8i

Please help to solve this error

The react-native latest version:-

```
 System:
     OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
     react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
     react-native: 0.60.0 => 0.60.0    npmGlobalPackages:
     react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

thanks

Comment: I also  checked  with link but https://prnt.sc/oaxxuc this error shows when i run,(latest version  react-native 0.60.0 no need to link )

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ob0f0o this error now showing ,how to fix

Comment: Your packager server is trying to serve a react-native version that doesn't match what is installed in your app. If you've just upgraded your react-native version, restart your server with `npm start -- --reset-cache` to clear the cache issue. If you didn't then you probably have another package running for another project

Comment: Its solved above prblm,but still showing this error (https://prnt.sc/oaxxuc ),when i link react-native link react-native-gesture-handler command,I  also checked without linking same error showing in the latest react-native version

Comment: This issue has been posted on github and you can apply the following solution.
It will work for the RN 0.60.0. https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/642#issuecomment-509113481

Answer (score 3):

You should paste import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; on the top of index.js which is standard in react native out of the box.

the entry of your app. This is the file where you import your App.js file, its written clearly in the documentations.

documents here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're on React Native >= 0.60, you need to disable autolinking for react-native-gesture-handler first. To disable autolinking for it, create a react-native.config.js file in the root of your project with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-gesture-handler': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

for react-native-gesture-handle 2 version onwards we just need to following changes at App.js

```
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


export default function App() {
  return <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>{/* content */}</GestureHandlerRootView>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by documentation

**On Android RNGH does not work by default because modals are not located under React Native Root view in native hierarchy. To fix that, components need to be wrapped with gestureHandlerRootHOC**

```
const ExampleWithHoc = gestureHandlerRootHOC(() => (
    <View>
      <DraggableBox />
    </View>
  );
);

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <Modal>
      <ExampleWithHoc />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

[Here the documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation#android)

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled newArchEnabled=false in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade from 1.1.0 -> 1.0.16 and use exact version(-E):

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.16 -D -E
```